# Dictionary Error - Jupyter Notebook - Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

This function was working fine before, and I can't see what has gone wrong with it now. Below is the function, the error, and the hypJson dictionary in that order. Even when i comment out this specific section, I get the same error in other sections that do the same tasks. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```html
for idx, row in dfT1.iterrows():
    hypJson = json.loads(row['hyperparameters'])
    if hypJson['dropout'] not in d1:
        d1[hypJson['dropout']] = (row['test_accuracy'] * len(row['test_labels'], len(row['test_labels']))
        t1count[hypJson['dropout']] = 1
    else:
        d1[hypJson['dropout']] = (d1[hypJson['dropout']][0] + row['test_accuracy'] * len(row['test_labels']), #correct
                             d1[hypJson['dropout']][1] + len(row['test_labels'])) #total
        t1count[hypJson['dropout']] = t1count[hypJson['dropout']] + 1
```

```html
  File "<ipython-input-19-1326a1a48cb8>", line 11
    t1count[hypJson['dropout']] = 1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```html
{'dropout': 0, 'optimizer': 'sgd-001-0.9-nesterov', 'deep-dense-top': False, 'convnet-freeze-percent': 0}
{'dropout': 0, 'optimizer': 'sgd-001-0.9', 'deep-dense-top': False, 'convnet-freeze-percent': 0}
{'dropout': 0, 'optimizer': 'adam', 'deep-dense-top': False, 'convnet-freeze-percent': 0}
{'dropout': 0.1, 'optimizer': 'sgd-001-0.9-nesterov', 'deep-dense-top': False, 'convnet-freeze-percent': 0}
{'dropout': 0.1, 'optimizer': 'sgd-001-0.9', 'deep-dense-top': False, 'convnet-freeze-percent': 0}
{'dropout': 0.1, 'optimizer': 'adam', 'deep-dense-top': False, 'convnet-freeze-percent': 0}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing bracket ')' in the line before the one shown in the SyntaxError

Comment: @dm2 thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line above has unbalanced parentheses:

```
d1[hypJson['dropout']] = (row['test_accuracy'] * len(row['test_labels'], len(row['test_labels']))
                                                                    ^^^^ here
```

It should've been:

```
d1[hypJson['dropout']] = (row['test_accuracy'] * len(row['test_labels']), len(row['test_labels']))
```

Python will often report syntax error on the line *after* the one with the syntax error because that missing closing parenthesis isn't a syntax error per se, so it keeps scanning the code until it finds something that's *definitely* a syntax error, like the `(...) t1count` in your case:

```
... = (row['test_accuracy'] * len(row['test_labels'], len(row['test_labels']))
t1count[hypJson['dropout']] = 1
^^^^^^^^ this is seen as (stuff)t1count, which is a syntax error
```